# form data not parsing in nodejs, mongoose while using validator joi (postman)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, form-data, joi

While I am using data validator joi, form data is not parsed in nodejs but without data validator middleware, code works well.
Mention to that I used express.urlencoded({ extended: true })
and this middleware is used before defining authRoutes.
while using in postman, if I select input as raw json, code works well, but in case of form-data, code can't work.
How can I solve this problem, please help.

Thanks in advance.

I tried so many times, but not working.
I was expecting form data should be parsed